# Auto add image to node listing from node body field

Tags: nodes, media, entities

Hi I have news content type, where are fields Title(textbox), Body(text with CKeditor) and Summary Image(multimedia asset). Is it possible to auto add first image from Body to summary image field?

Answer (score 0):

Install the [Token Filter](https://drupal.org/project/token_filter) module. That'll tell you what tokens available and from them choose the field that you want to display in the node body. So when you save the node the token will replace with the field value you want.

Comment: no, you didn't understand me. I have summary image(multimedia asset) where I can choose image and it will be shown on listing news page. I just want to have possibility to show first image from content on listing news page, when no summary image was chosen.

Comment: You mean show a default image? when no image is attached with the summary.

Comment: exactly, but this default image will be chosen automatically from news body(which is created via CKeditor).

Comment: Create a tpl file for that content type and place it in your theme folder, node--CONTENTYYPE.tpl and check for your field value in tpl file. $node->field_SUMMARY will give you the associative array of the field. If that's empty print your default image there.